# Function call not working in callback

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype

I've created an object with its own prototype functions and member variables. If I do this:

```
var obj = new MyObject(options); // this.options takes the value of options
obj.doThis();
obj.doThat();
```

...then everything is fine. But if I do this:

```
var obj = new MyObject(options);
obj.doThis();
setTimeout(obj.doThat, 3000);
```

...then it crashes when `doThat` gets fired. The error reports that `options`, which is set in the constructor, is `undefined`. The 2 functions are being added to the prototype like:

```
MyObject.prototype.doThat = (function() {
    ...
    ...
})();
```

I'm a Javascript beginner, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are many duplicates of this basic issue.

Comment: Fair enough, I just didn't know how to express my question properly enough to find the right answer. Will I delete the question ??

Comment: Oh I wasn't complaining or chastising you; indeed, I meant it in the opposite sense. It's a common point of confusion and it seems really weird coming from a C++ or Java background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout(obj.doThat, 3000)`, `doThat` isn’t bound to `obj`. It’s just a free function. `this` is bound in JavaScript by calling:

```
f(); // this is undefined or the global object, depending on strict mode
x.f(); // this is x
x['f'](); // this is still x
f.call(x, arg1, arg2); // this is, again, x
f.apply(x, [arg1, arg2]); // guess
```

ECMAScript 5, however, does offer a function on functions to return a function to call the function with a specific `this`. It’s called `bind`:

```
setTimeout(MyObject.prototype.doThat.bind(obj), 3000);
```

Comment: `...a function on functions to return a function to call the function...` Oh, Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
setTimeout(obj.doThat, 3000);
```

You are passing the *function* and only the function. The context of `obj` is lost.

You need to create (and pass) a new function that calls `doThat` in the context of `obj`.

[The `bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will do that.

```
setTimeout(obj.doThat.bind(obj), 3000);
```

(Note, [limited browser support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind), a polyfill is available at the above link)